# To Calculate Location, is GeoCoordinateWatcher using GPS or A-GPS

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps

I am using GeoCoordinateWatcher to get my current location. have these questions.

1) I want to know if GeoCoordinatewatcher can use satelite signal (GPS) to calculate my current location.

2) I understand there is a different between GPS and A-GPS. What is A-GPS.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes GeoCordinateWatcher can use satellite signals to calculate your current location.

A-GPS is Assisted GPS and is basically GPS with improved startup times. Pretty sure WP7 uses it.

Link [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS)

Comment: @SteveChadbourne: ThankQ very much. Say, I am in the center of a soccer field, my GPS location should be approx say 10 feet or 20 feet in radius but if I get a GPS reading suggest that 400 meter. so, is this calcaluation base on satelite Signal or base on A-GPS which uses nearBy base station as the Location? How do I verfiry GPS is used in WP7?

Comment: You can filter by accuracy. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dragoman/archive/2010/09/21/wp7-code-using-the-geolocation-api.aspx

Comment: You can also specify what sort of accuracy you require like this: var watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High); You can't verify that GPS is being used - you may get a high accuracy just on cell tower position.

Comment: @SteveChadbourn: Thanks. Will do some testing and report back later

Comment: Assisted GPS uses the cell network and WiFi hotspots to improve the accuracy of the position, especially for built-up areas.

Comment: @SteveChadbourn: GeoPositionAccuracy.High wont help It seems Windows phone has ONLY A-GPS. There is no GPS base on Satelite signal. I had tried many times and many different locations to verify.

Comment: Don't understand what you mean by no GPS base on Satellite signal? - A-GPS is GPS with additional help, not pseudo-gps.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne: A-GPS is a kind of GPS BUT its Lat/Lon Base on Cell_TowerID and its radius can be 1 mile. GPS base on Satelite signal is MORE accurate Lat/Lon such as 4 meter in radius. The GeoCoordinateWatcher can not perform GPS base on satelite. This is my finding. so, I hope some1 can help to clarify.

Comment: A-GPS is not kind of GPS. A-GPS is GPS with added helpers. Look at it as GPS+. It starts out with cell towers and wi-fi hotspots to speed up startup time or when GPS not available. To test this turn off wi-fi and phone connection then test gps functionality.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne: Great! Now GPS+ is better way for me to understand. It get the Cell-ID first WHILE processing the Accurate LatLon. I need your help on your instruction : 1) Turn off connection. Which Connection? Data Connection in Setting Menu or Connection SetUp? 2) How long it takes to override the first Cell-ID LatLon. I begin to see it from your side. Thank

Comment: Try turning flight mode on. Not sure if this disables GPS. Otherwise Turn off Wi-Fi, Data connection and 3G from settings.

Comment: @SteveChadbourne: ThankQ. I did try your suggestion. It seems it works. This means also that all Windows phone have GPS and A-GPS.